# crasheo de programa al usar array de estructuras

Tags: c++

Practicaba un ejercicio sobre arrays de estructuras en C++ y el programa funcionaba bien al principio al ingresar datos de los estudiantes luego el programa al querer mostrar da crash, lo depuré y arroja el error "segmentation fault" justo en la llamada a la función mostrar, el intento que hice al querer arreglar es evitar usar un puntero tipo `char` porque a juzgar por el mensaje del compilador estaré tocando sin saber un área de memoria que no es mía.

Precisamente usó el puntero tipo `char` ya que tuve un error de conversión inválida de `char` a `const char` (*invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char* *')

La captura del crasheo :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código :

```
/*
crear una estructura llamada alumno la cual se tendrá los siguientes campos
nombre
edad
promedio

calcular cual de los tres es el mejor promedio y posteriormente mostrar los datos del alumno destacado
*/

#include<iostream>

struct alumno{
    char nombre[40];
    int edad;
    float promedio;
}std1[3];

float mejor;

char band = (char*)'n';

void pedir();

void mostrar();

int main()
{
    pedir();
    mostrar();
    return 0;
}

void pedir()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        std::cout<<"\nnombre : ";
        std::cin.getline(std1[i].nombre,40,'\n');
        std::cout<<"\nedad : ";
        std::cin>>std1[i].edad;
        std::cout<<"\npromedio : ";
        std::cin>>std1[i].promedio;
    }
    if((std1[0].promedio>std1[1].promedio) && (std1[0].promedio>std1[2].promedio))
    {
        band = (char*)'0';
        mejor = std1[0].promedio;
    }
    else if((std1[1].promedio>std1[2].promedio) && (std1[1].promedio>std1[0].promedio))
    {
        band = (char*)'1';
        mejor = std1[1].promedio;
    }
    else{
        band = (char*)'2';
        mejor = std1[2].promedio;
    }

}
void mostrar()
{
    if(strcmp(band,(char*)'0')==0)
    {
        std::cout<<"\nel mejor promedio es del estudiante 1 "<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"nombre : "<<std1[0].nombre<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"edad : "<<std1[0].edad<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"promedio : "<<std1[0].promedio<<std::endl;
        
    }
    else if(strcmp(band,(char*)'1')==0)
    {
        
        std::cout<<"\nel mejor promedio es del estudiante 2 "<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"nombre : "<<std1[1].nombre<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"edad : "<<std1[1].edad<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"promedio : "<<std1[1].promedio<<std::endl;  
    }
    else{
        
        std::cout<<"\nel mejor promedio es del estudiante 3 "<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"nombre : "<<std1[2].nombre<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"edad : "<<std1[2].edad<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"promedio : "<<std1[2].promedio<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué se debe el typecast a un tipo puntero que será guardado en una variable normal? Sospecho que tu código puede estar fallando en alguna de las líneas en las que haces eso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> luego el programa al querer mostrar da crash, lo depuré y arroja el error "segmentation fault" justo en la llamada a la función mostrar

Es normal que esto suceda, viendo lo que has hecho en la función `mostrar` he tenido un par de infartitos. Necesitaremos un poco de contexto para entender qué es lo que has hecho mal.

---

##### Primero ¿Qué es un literal?.

Un literal es una representación de un concepto: por ejemplo un número. Imagina el número tres. Sabes exactamente qué significa el concepto "tres" y será el mismo lo representes como lo representes, en cualquier idioma, en cualquier lenguaje de programación, en cualquier base numérica, en cualquier punto del universo y en cualquier momento del tiempo.

Un literal, es la representación de ese concepto, así en el código siguiente:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    x += 3;
```

Tenemos tres literales, el primero `0` representa el concepto cero. Los siguientes `3` y `3` representan el concepto tres, los literales iguales son intercambiables e indistinguibles el uno del otro porque representan lo mismo, no puedes decir que un tres es diferente de otro tres porque ambos son el mismo concepto: ambos son el Literal del concepto tres y en cualquier parte de tu código o del código de otras personas seguirá siendo exactamente lo mismo: podemos decir **literalmente** que cualquier tres es exactamente el mismo tres.

El literal numérico es el más fácil de comprender y por eso lo he escogido para ilustrar la idea de "Literal", pero el mismo concepto de "literalidad" es aplicable a otras cosas, como por ejemplo letras, al principio de tu código escribes esto:

```
char band = (char*)'n';
```

Hay fallos tan graves en tan pocos caracteres que me sorprende que el código siquiera compile:

1. **No coincide el tipo de la variable con el tipo del inicializador**, y debería coincidir: La variable `band` es de tipo `char`, pero le asignas un valor de tipo `char*`:

   ```
      char band = (char*)'n';
   // ^^^^        ^^^^^^^ <--- Tipo del inicializador: 'char*'
   //   \
   //    \___ Tipo de la variable = 'char'
   ```
2. **Transformas un literal de carácter (`'u'`) en un puntero a carácter**: Al carácter `'u'` le corresponde el valor numérico `117`, que lo transformas a puntero (cuyo valor sería, en 32 bits: `0x00000075`) para que después sea implícitamente transformado de nuevo a carácter para poderlo guardar en `band`.
3. **No puedes transformar un literal de carácter en puntero a carácter**: Para empezar, no puedes obtener la dirección de memoria de un literal, porque son una idea conceptual, no un elemento real; para acabar, al convertir un literal de carácter en un puntero sólo obtendrás una dirección de una zona de memoria que no estás gestionando.

##### Segundo, se masca la tragedia: el fiasco con `strcmp`.

Como su propio nombre indica, la función `strcmp` compara cadenas de caracteres (`str`ing `c`o`mp`arison). Remarco: compara ***cadenas de caracteres***. Una cadena de caracteres (como su nombre indica) son caracteres anexos, *encadenados* uno tras otro.

Esta función espera recibir dos punteros a carácter, cada uno de los punteros debe apuntar a un espacio de memoria con caracteres anexos y finalizando con el carácter nulo `'\0'`. Y eso no es lo que le estás facilitando a la función, de hecho me sorprende que el código siquiera compile:

```
strcmp(band,(char*)'0')
//     ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^ <--- El literal de caracter '0' tiene valor 48, 
//       \                    convertido a puntero es '0x00000030'.
//        \
//         \___ 'band' es de tipo 'char', pero strcmp espera un 'char*'
```

Suponiendo que eso realmente compile, a la función `strcmp` le estás pidiendo que compare como si fuesen dos cadenas de caracteres lo que sea que exista en la memoria  a la que apunta `band` (que será `0x00000030`, `0x00000031` o `0x00000032`) con lo que exista en la memoria a la que apunta `(char*)'0'` (que será `0x00000030`). Como dichas direcciones de memoria no las gestiona tu programa, éste responde con el fallo (crash).

##### Tercero, propuesta de solución.

Malas noticias: tu código no tiene solución. Hay que rehacerlo:

1. En C++ las cadenas de caracteres se gestionan con el objeto `std::string`, no con formaciones de caracteres con tamaño prefijado.

   ```
   struct alumno{
       std::string nombre; // ¡Bien!
       int edad;
       float promedio;
   }std1[3];
   ```

   Además, `std::string` incorpora el operador de comparación `==`, así no necesitas usar el arcaico `strcmp`.
2. Es mala práctica abusar de variables globales.

   ```
   struct alumno{
       char nombre[40];
       int edad;
       float promedio;
   }std1[3]; // ¡Mal!

   float mejor; // ¡Mal!

   char band = (char*)'n'; // ¡Mal!
   ```
3. Para buscar el mayor valor de una colección de valores, encadenar `if` es lo menos práctico y escalable. Usa bucles.
4. Sigue el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) en tus funciones, la función `pedir` debería pedir datos no pedirlos y hacer cálculos con ellos.

Si reescribimos tu código en C++ moderno, podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct alumno
{
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;
    float promedio;
};

void pedir(alumno &a)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    std::cout << "\nnombre : ";
    std::getline(std::cin, a.nombre);
    std::cout << "\nedad : ";
    std::cin >> a.edad;
    std::cout << "\npromedio : ";
    std::cin >> a.promedio;
}

void mostrar(const alumno (&alumnos)[3])
{
    auto mejor = std::max_element(std::begin(alumnos), std::end(alumnos),
        [](const alumno &a, const alumno &b) { return a.promedio < b.promedio; });

        std::cout
        << "\nel mejor promedio es del estudiante " << std::distance(alumnos, mejor)
        << "\nnombre : " << mejor->nombre
        << "\nedad : " << mejor->edad
        << "\npromedio : " << mejor->promedio << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    alumno std1[3]{};

    for (auto &a : std1)
        pedir(a);

    mostrar(std1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: gracias me ha corregido bastantes conceptos erróneos del  lenguaje , e igualmente gracias por explicar parte por parte mis errores.